# EventHandler de una nueva función, no funciona cuando se llama desde otro EventHandler VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vba, eventos, vb

> NUNCA SE DISPARA EL EVENTO SI SE LLAMA DESDE SBO_Application_ItemEvent
>   PERO DESDE test3 FUNCIONA, hay algún problema si se llama una función con un evento desde otro evento ?

**Esta es la clase principal que me presenta el problema**

```
Public Class InvoiceDocumentButtons

        Public Sub test3()
            Dim SendDocuments As New SendDocumentInvoice
            SendDocuments.test()
        End Sub

        Private Sub SBO_Application_ItemEvent(ByVal FormUID As String, ByRef pVal As SAPbouiCOM.ItemEvent, ByRef BubbleEvent As Boolean) Handles SBO_Application.ItemEvent
            Dim SendDocuments As New SendDocumentInvoice
            SendDocuments.test()
        End Sub

    End Class


Public Class SendDocumentInvoice

    Public WithEvents DISPAPELES_Ws As consultarArchivos

    Public Sub test()
        DISPAPELES_Ws = New com.dispafel.consultarpdfxmlfactura.consultarArchivos
        DISPAPELES_Ws.CallconsultarArchivosAsync(felConsultaFacturaArchivo)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DISPAPELES_Ws_CallconsultarArchivosCompleted(sender As Object, e As CallconsultarArchivosCompletedEventArgs) Handles DISPAPELES_Ws.CallconsultarArchivosCompleted
        NUNCA SE DISPARA EL EVENTO SI SE LLAMA DESDE SBO_Application_ItemEvent PERO DESDE test3 FUNCIONA
    End Sub

End Class
```